# ControlTextDidChange not called on setStringValue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I've implemented a delegate and its `controlTextDidChange` method it is called whenever i enter text in the `NSTextField`.

When I set text programmatically via `[field setStringValue:@"newText"]` the `controlTextDidChange` is NOT called.

Could you please explain this? And how I should programmatically set a new value that triggers invocation of my delegate's method `controlTextDidChange`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `controlTextDidChange` delegate is only triggered on user interaction,
updating the `NSControl` manually does by design not trigger the delegate.

**Proper Solution**

The solution is to create a separate method to handle the text change:

```
- (void)myCustomFunction {
     // Triggered in case the text is changed,
     // no matter by user or programmatically
}
```

Trigger this method from the delegate:

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self myCustomFunction];
}
```

And in case the text is changed programmatically:

```
[theField setStringValue:@"text"];
[self myCustomFunction];
```

Now you can handle both situation within the same method.

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger the function `controlTextDidChange` programmatically

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: NSControlTextDidChangeNotification
                                                    object:textFieldExample
                                                  userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [[textFieldExample window] fieldEditor:YES
                                                                                                                           forObject:textFieldExample]
                                                                                       forKey:@"NSFieldEditor"]];
```

this is more useful, when `controlTextDidChange` is triggered by more than one textFields!

Answer (score 1):

Oliver P's answer ported to Swift 4.0:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(
    name: NSControl.textDidChangeNotification,
    object: textFieldExample,
    userInfo: ["NSFieldEditor":
        textFieldExample!.fieldEditor(true, for: textFieldExample)!])
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was sufficient to call this, without any `userInfo` (Swift 5):

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSControl.textDidChangeNotification, object: myTextField)
```